Como mapear uma propriedade nullable no EF 9?
Qual a maneira correta para mapear uma propriedade nullable?
public record Description(string Value)
{
    public string Value { get; private set; } = Value;
    
    public static implicit operator string(Description description) => description.Value;
    public static implicit operator Description(string value) => new Description(value);
}

public class TestEntity : Entity
{
    public Description? Description { get; private set; }
    public int Total { get; private set; }
    
    private TestEntity() : base(Guid.CreateVersion7()){ }

    public TestEntity(Guid companyId,
        string description,
        int total) : base(companyId)
    {
        Description = description;
        Total = total;
    }
}

public class TestEntityMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TestEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TestEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("TestEntity");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.HasIndex(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_TestEntity_Id")
            .IsUnique();            
            
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Description, description =>
        {
            description.Property(x => x.Value)
                .HasColumnName("Description")
                .IsRequired(false);
        });
        
        builder.Property(x => x.Total)
            .HasColumnName("Total")
            .IsRequired(true);
    }
}

Quando tento executar o comando para gerar a migration recebo esse warning

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20606]
The entity type 'Description' is an optional dependent using table sharing without any required non shared property that could be used to identify whether the entity exists. If all nullable properties contain a null value in database then an object instance won't be created in the query. Add a required property to create instances with null values for other properties or mark the incoming navigation as required to always create an instance.
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'


pq essa complexidade de criar um record "Description" para uma única propriedade string? não seria mais simples na sua entidade "Description" ser uma string diretamente?

de qualquer forma, para fazer isso "Description" deve ser uma outra entidade no seu modelo certo? Se não for, deveria mapear como uma propriedade string, mas se for, esse mapping de OwnsOne me parece estranho, sugiro ler a documetação: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

De fato, mas se considerarmos que eu faça um VO para e-mail.
Cairei no mesmo problema. Considerando este novo cenário, qual a forma mais adequada de eu tratar isso?
Pois pode acontecer de uma entidade o e-mail ser nullable e em outra entidade ser obrigatório.

O problema é que, como a sua entidade Description pode ser nula dentro da entidade TestEntity, Description precisa ter alguma propriedade não-nula, ou Required. Tente mapear "Value" como required, não sei se isso vai funcionar bem com um record, para testar mude para uma class comum caso não funcione. Posso redigir uma resposta explicando o pq disso, mas antes veja se isso resolve o seu problema :)

Cara, funcionou! Mudei para class e coloquei IsRequired(true) no mapeamento...
Ele criou certinho no banco. Agora fico no aguardo da sua explicação hahaha para eu entender PORQUE passando IsRequired(true) no mapeamento criou a coluna como nullable no banco.

boa... pronto repondido, o fato de mudar para classe é simplesmente pq eu não tinha certeza de como o EF ia enteder o valor não nulo nesse caso

Para entender o problema, vamos pegar o primeiro parágrafo do erro (em tradução livre):

O tipo de entidade 'Descrição' é um dependente opcional que usa
compartilhamento de tabela, sem nenhuma propriedade não
compartilhada necessária que poderia ser usada para identificar se a
entidade existe.

Significa que, se uma entidade é dependente e opcional (nullable, IsRequired(false), etc), o Entityframework não consegue validar se essa entidade existe, o que pode levar a um problema de perda de dados, por exemplo não adicionando dados nas tabelas dependentes.
Em outras palavras, se uma classe tem por exemplo apenas uma propridade nullable, como saber se ela existe (se há uma instância) já que a propriedade pode ser nula?
Podemos ter uma instância da classe com o valor da propriedade a nulo, mas não garante que é um valor válido.
Dai a necessidade de ao menos uma propriedade não ser nula. Isso vai forçar a haver no mínimo dados nessa propriedade, indicando que a tabela existe (se houver uma instância, é possível verificar porque a propriedade deve ter um valor).
Isso era um problema que existia no Entityframework, e foi corrigido depois da versão 6, e está documentado porque gerou uma break changing, ou seja, códigos que estavam como o seu, começaram a gerar erro de compilação, pode ver a explicação completa aqui: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/nested-optionals
Por fim, a solução está, além de explicada no link acima, também no texto da própria excessão, que podemos ver abaixo, em tradução livre:

Adicione uma propriedade necessária para criar instâncias com valores nulos para outras propriedades ou marque a navegação de
entrada como necessária para sempre criar uma instância.

E é isso, na classe associada basta ter uma propriedade não nula para deixar o EF contente :)
